# “I am not going to use it recently” Is this technically correct?

Tags: present-tense

I want to say I'm not going to use something in the recent future. Can I say it like “I am not going to use it recently”?

Comment: You want to say “I’m not going to use it soon.”

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Recent* refers always to the past, never the future. *I have not used it recently.*

You can say *I am not going to use it in the near future* or *any time soon.*

Comment: Yes, you'd need a time machine to have experienced the recent future:-) Strangely, though, I think I have seen 'the near past' on occasions, but I can't be sure.